# How to randomly choose between few values with different probabilities in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, random, distribution

I'm trying to generate a dummy data to test my Reporting Application. So far I have something this,

```
    Dim list As List(Of Object)
    Dim random As System.Random = New System.Random()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        Dim obj As New Object
        If random.Next(0, 3) > 0 Then
            obj.Country = "China"
        Else
            obj.Country = "Japan"
        End If
        ...
        list.add(obj)
    Next
```

This working nicely. However I want to be able to random more Country, say 5 (`China, Japan, South Korea, North Korea, Taiwan`) with probability `0.4 : 0.3 : 0.1 : 0.1 : 0.1` respectively.

I know I can just extend the `If` statement above, but I really want avoid messy code since the purpose is only to generate dummy data.

While the current above code may can be simplified using Ternary Operator, how can I do that if I need to random between 5 values? Is there any other choice other than `If - Else` statement?

Comment: Do you want to get a list with 100 entries that really have this distribution, or to generate each item with the given probability?

Comment: @Wolf I just need to generate with the given probability. I think the answer below is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urm, the simplest solution I can think so far is:

```
Dim list As List(Of Object)
Dim random As System.Random = New System.Random()
Dim Countries() As String = {"China", "China", "China", "China", _
                             "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", _
                             "South Korea", _
                             "North Korea", _
                             "Taiwan"}

For i As Integer = 1 To 100
    Dim obj As New Object
    obj.Country = Countries(random.Next(0, 10))
    ...
    list.add(obj)
Next
```

Comment: The problem here is that you have to think about translating probabilities into literal code...

Comment: @Wolf Generally the array `Countries()` values already handles the probabilities. The chances of getting `China` is `4/10`, `Japan(3/10)`, `South Korea(1/10)`, `North Korea(1/10)` and `Taiwan(1/0)`

Comment: Sorry, a misunderstanding: I mean, whenever you add a country or change a probability, than there is much work to do.